# Problem with Jackson (JSON) parsing Map with ArrayList inside using ObjectMapper and PolymorphicTypeValidator without tags

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jbpm, objectmapper

I have read many posts about JSON parsing but still trying to resolve errors passing a java.util.HashMap that contains a class with a java.util.ArrayList inside it. I am ultimately passing this to JBPM. I have been trying to avoid using tags to avoid adding another dependency in Business Central (although perhaps *Business Central* might need this information too for JSON parsing.

More specifically, I have the project with a POJO and 2 classes:

```
public class AmsUsers {
    private List<AmsUser> peoplePayload;
...

public class AmsUser {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
...
```

This project is a transitive dependency to my client in my project called RESTProject that makes REST calls to JBPM.  JBPM imports the object model project.  When I call my REST client via a JUnit which uses:

```
private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
...
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build();
mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS); 
URIBuilder ub = new URIBuilder(url);
AmsUser u1 = new AmsUser("my id"....);
AmsUser u2 = new AmsUser("second id"....);
ArrayList<AmsUser> names = new ArrayList<AmsUser>();
names.add(u1);
names.add(u2);
AmsUsers users = new AmsUsers();
users.setPeoplePayload(names);
hash.put(MAP_USERS_ASSIGNING_KEY, users);
String hashMapString = mapper.writeValueAsString(hash);
```

I get the following logged:

```
handling map of parameters for {
"people":["com.goprecise.ams.AmsUsers",{"peoplePayload":["java.util.ArrayList",[
{"id":"AA8E0125-EED9-4682-0000-5BAA665FC2F7","firstName":"D",.... },
{"id":"AA8E0125-EED9-4682-0001-5BAA665FC2F7","firstName":"David", ... }
]]}]}

could not parse map Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Map
```

How do I get the classes in ArrayList passed to indicate that it is ArrayList of AmsUser's without annotations or custom code?  Do I need to just accept annotating the classes (which would add dependencies in Business Central but could *help* it do its JSON parsing as well)?  If so, what annotations should I use? Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of your 'hash' ? Try declaring the reference with concrete type like `HashMap` instead of `Map`

Comment: Try using `ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL`

Comment: @YuvarajG  I believe it is a HashMap<String,Object>.   I will try NON-FINAL, since that seems even more permissive.  I tried allowing individual types, without luck.